# How to generate avro ocf format(with schema) data/file using scala?

Tags: scala, avro, avro4s

I am new bee to Scala.

I have a requirement where my data (in case class) needs to be written to S3 bucket in avro OCF(schema included) format.
I could see ways to generate/serialise avro non-ocf(schemaless) format data in scala but could not find the way to generate OCF format.

This link example shows how to generate non-OCF format, but I am looking for OCF format generation
https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-avro-scala-example

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `com.sksamuel.avro4s.AvroDataOutputStream` class.